# How is the second-order difference equation derived?

Tags: time-series

I'm reading through some [documentation](https://otexts.com/fpp2/backshift.html) on timeseries.

The first-order difference for timeseries is given as:

$y'_{t} = y_{t} - y_{t-1}$

The second-order difference for timeseries is given as:

$y''_{t} = y_{t} - 2y_{t - 1} + y_{t - 2}$

How is the second-order equation derived? I was thinking that it should be the following but this doesn't make sense ...

$y''_{t} = y'_{t} - y_{t-2} = (y_{t} - y_{t-1}) - y_{t-2}$

Simple answers preferred over complex answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second difference is defined as the **difference of the first difference**. That is, it is $$y'_t - y'_{t-1} = (y_t - y_{t-1}) - (y_{t-1}-y_{t-2}) = y_t - 2y_{t-1} + y_{t-2}.$$